# Installing apk programmatically Intent not opening

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download and install an apk, this works just fine for Android versions less than 9, but 10 and 11 never reach the package installer and reloads whole the app.

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(PATH));
Intent intent;
    
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
              intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE, fileUri);
              intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
    
              intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
              intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    
              intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    
              intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            } else {
              intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
              intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }
    
  context.startActivity(intent);
```

And it throws this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/app-name.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10008001 (has extras) }
```

This is the Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.appname" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

    <application>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException` on Android 7.0+. Use `FileProvider`, not `Uri.fromFile()`.

Comment: `No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW ` ? ACTION_VIEW?